# Is there any function to send airtime using Reloadly API

Tags: php, curl

I have tried reloadly API stated on their doc but no success, i could not find exactly the correct API end point to make Curl call.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://topups.reloadly.com/accounts/balance
");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Accept: application/com.reloadly.topups-v1+json",
  "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik0wWXpRa"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

I got from their their API doc https://topupsapi.docs.apiary.io it stated on sending airtime but no correct endpoint stated. thank

Is there any function or correct endpoint i didn't know about?

Comment: Please include the error message you are seeing when you run the provided code or any other reason you believe it is not working.

Comment: error message https://imgur.com/4r0NX7O

Comment: `Reloadly` tag does not exist yet. I removed the API tag, which you should not use. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the endpoint is https://topups.reloadly.com/topups , and it's supposed to look something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://topups.reloadly.com/topups',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Accept: application/com.reloadly.topups-v1+json",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSU",
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array(
        'recipientPhone' => array(
            'countryCode' => 'HT',
            'number' => '+50936377111',
        ),
        'senderPhone' => array(
            'countryCode' => 'US',
            'number' => '+13059547862',
        ),
        'operatorId' => 173,
        'amount' => 15,
        'customIdentifier' => 'transaction by john@example.com',
    ))
));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a million... am gonna tried it right away and feedback you in sec

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://topups.reloadly.com/topups',
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Accept: application/com.reloadly.topups-v1+json",
    "Authorization: Bearer your_access_token")),
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array(
    'recipientPhone' => array(
        'countryCode' => 'HT',
        'number' => '+50936377111'
    ),
    'senderPhone' => array(
        'countryCode' => 'US',
        'number' => '+13059547862'
    ),
    'operatorId' => 173,
    'amount' => 15,
    'customIdentifier' => 'transaction by john@example.com'
    ))
    ));
          $response = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          echo '<pre>';
          var_dump($response);
          echo '</pre>';
       [enter image description here][1]?>
```

Comment: It is usually useful to include some test to explain how this code solves the problem.

Comment: you just need  to replace your "your_access_token" by   your token that you generate from your cleint_id and client_secret